# I want a div near another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've this piece of code

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="border: solid 2px blue">
        <div class="text-center" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); border: solid 2px red; height:35px;">
            Some text
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <img ng-src="/static/images/insegne/{{ insegna.id }}.jpg" style="width:120px; height:120px; border:solid 2px white;" ng-click="vm.onInsegnaClicked(insegna)" />
        </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the div bordered to red near the div that contain the image. How I can do it? I attempt to add a pull-left class at the red div, but doesn't work.

Comment: add snippet of it. @Dennis

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gw2q6efv/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think you want  something or somewhere like this? See it in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your structure to like this and it will work .

```
 <div class="col-md-3" style="border: solid 2px blue">

<div class="pull-right">
    <img ng-src="/static/images/insegne/{{ insegna.id }}.jpg" style="width:120px; height:120px; border:solid 2px white;" ng-click="vm.onInsegnaClicked(insegna)" />
</div>
<div class="text-center pull-right" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); border: solid 2px red; height:35px;">
    Some text
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using display flex, also without bootstrap, so is this :

```css
.cont{
  display:flex;
}
.left .right{
  flex-grow:1
 }
```

```html
<div class="cont" style="border: solid 2px blue;padding:20px;">

        <div class="left" style="transform: rotate(-90deg); border: solid 2px red; height:35px;">
            Some text
        </div>
        
        <div class="right">
            <img ng-src="/static/images/insegne/{{ insegna.id }}.jpg" style="width:120px; height:120px; border:solid 2px white;" ng-click="vm.onInsegnaClicked(insegna)" />
        </div>
        
</div>
```